# how to create a simple radio station

Tags: internet

I've been digging around for ages but not getting very far so any links or tips would be massively appreciated.

I want to create a central "radio station" in my home to stream one playlist to any computers pointing their browser to the ip within my internal network.

I have an old mini slave mac mini running ubuntu and was originally thinking I could get php and apache to handle this but then quickly realised that of course, php will serve out streaming independently per connection ie no radio station.

Are there any servers already built for this sort of behaviour?

is [shoutcast](https://serverfault.com/questions/307367/intranet-radio-station-over-network#answer-307421) one of the only versions

Thanks,
John

Comment: Questions about home environments are *specifically* identified as off-topic [in the Help Center](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). In production/professional environments, this is the sort of project you would have to research (Google up some options, determine the pros and cons, and make a business case for/against each) prior to implementation - Server Fault [does not provide product/service recommendations](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: It is illegal to stream and/or broadcast music for which you don't have the proper licensing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can look at doing this with IP Multicast, and something like VLC.  Setup your playlist in VLC, and then using the streaming wizard tell it to stream to network using UDP multicast. Giving it a class-d address (something like 239.1.2.3 should be fine).  Stream it using RTP.  then any RTP player should be able to listen to the stream. and since it is multicast there will always only be 1 copy of the stream on your lan, and everybody will have the same version.

Comment: +1 I've used this exact approach before, works pretty darn well.